# Consultas de select en Tkinter y Python

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, select

soy nuevo el programacion en Python con Tkinter, deseo hacer una consulta Select desde una captura Query que es la siguiente

```
self.entry11=tk.Entry(self.pagina1, width=11)
self.entry11.place(x=300,y=130)
```

la consulta (busqueda) se activa con un boton

```
self.boton12=ttk.Button(self.pagina1, text="Busca  DNI", command=busca_dni)
self.boton12.place(x=380,y=130)
```

y este es el procedimiento busca_dni

```
def busca_dni(self):
    conexion=sqlite3.connect("Edcar.db")
    self.dni=tk.StringVar()
    self.dni.set(self.entry11.get())
    cursor=conexion.execute("select nomcli from Cli01 where doccli=?",[self.dni])
```

y me da este error

TypeError: busca_dni() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Espero sus comentarios
Gracias

Comment: Hola Rafael, aunque no muestras la implementación completa de la clase, `busca_dni` es un método de instancia, debes llamarlo como tal, es decir: `command=self.busca_dni`